# catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash: No such file or directory

Tags: ros2, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Each time I open terminal I get this message

```
bash: /home/yograj/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash: No such file or directory
bash: /home/yograj/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash: No such file or directory
bash: /home/yograj/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash: No such file or directory
bash: /home/yograj/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash: No such file or directory
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281599/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash:-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [Nebula](https://answers.ros.org/users/33043/nebula/) on ROS Answers with karma: 98 on 2018-02-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved by editing bashrc. Open that file and remove those lines

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

---

Originally posted by [Nebula](https://answers.ros.org/users/33043/nebula/) with karma: 98 on 2018-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-02-02**:
Are you sure you copied the correct line into this answer? Because that line opens a gedit window to edit the **.bashrc** file itself.

**Comment by [Nebula](https://answers.ros.org/users/33043/nebula/) on 2018-02-02**:
Yes in that file (bashrc) I removed those statements.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

please double check if the path is there , if none , please run
catkin_make firstly , and then the setup.bash is generated automation .

---

Originally posted by [lsw](https://answers.ros.org/users/33525/lsw/) with karma: 46 on 2018-02-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1